# center zoom an image after clicking on it (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wrote a jquery function to zoom the image.
The first line hides all the images and the last line zooms the current image.
In between i have written code based on logic for displaying image in the center.
But it is not working, can anybody help?

```
     $("img").animate({opacity: "0.001", left: '0px'})

     var imgPosX = ( $(window).width() - $("this").width() )/2; 
     var imgPosY = ( $(window).height() - $("this").height() )/2; 

     $(this).css({"top": imgPosY+"px", "left": imgPosX+"px"}); 
     $(this).animate({opacity:"1", zoom: '150%'}, 'medium');},
```

Comment: what exactly does the `},` after the last line ? It's useless.

Comment: @EvilP he has not fully shown his function. So, it might be a continuation.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes thanks, did not take that into consideration :-D

Comment: Edit the comment, if not, the OP might remove it and may break his original code. :P

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `"`s surrounding `this`:

```
 var imgPosX = ( $(window).width() - $(this).width() )/2;
 var imgPosY = ( $(window).height() - $(this).height() )/2;
```

The [`this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) is a keyword in JavaScript not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a jQuery plugin since they're easy to find and do virtually anything you ask for.  Take a look at [this example](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/) for a possible alternative.  This has the added advantage that you can have thumbnails and load the full photo when you pass your mouse over (avoiding having to download all full-scale images at once).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing top and left try **margin-left and margin-right**

Comment: Doesn't work as the image has to be positioned `absolute` and `left` and `top` work best with `absolute` positioning. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/orimug/7/edit)

```
$(function(){

    $("img").css({opacity: "0.001", left: '0px'});

    objthis= $("img").eq(0);
     var imgPosX = ( $(window).width() - objthis.width() )/2; 
     var imgPosY = ( $(window).height() - objthis.height() )/2; 

     objthis.css({"position":"relative","top": imgPosY+"px", "left": imgPosX+"px"}); 
     objthis.animate({opacity:"1", zoom: '150%'}, 'medium'); 
});
```